# UnderscoreJS: Is there a way to iterate a JSON structure recursively?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

```
 var updateIconPathRecorsive = function (item) {
          if (item.iconSrc) {
              item.iconSrcFullpath = 'some value..';
          }

          _.each(item.items, updateIconPathRecorsive);
      };

      updateIconPathRecorsive(json);
```

Is there a better way that does not use a function?
I don't want to move the function away from the invocation because it is just like a sophisticated for. I'd probably want to be able to write something in the lines of:

```
   _.recursive(json, {children: 'items'}, function (item) {
      if (item.iconSrc) {
          item.iconSrcFullpath = 'some value..';
      }
   });
```

Comment: You need to reference the function at some point. Your first code snippet looks fine to me.

Comment: So basically what you want is an iterator on all object properties recursively?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an immediately-invoked named function expression:

```
(function updateIconPathRecorsive(item) {
    if (item.iconSrc) {
        item.iconSrcFullpath = 'some value..';
    }
    _.each(item.items, updateIconPathRecorsive);
})(json);
```

But your snippet is fine as well and will not [cause problems in IE](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#jscript-bugs).

There is no recursive wrapper function for underscore, and it doesn't provide a [Y-combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator) either. But if you want, you can easily [create one yourself](http://underscorejs.org/#mixin) of course:

```
_.mixin({
    recursive: function(obj, opt, iterator) {
        function recurse(obj) {
            iterator(obj);
            _.each(obj[opt.children], recurse);
        }
        recurse(obj);
    }
});
```